# Why is my Flutter class navigation widget returning Null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an App that has tiles that navigate to a new screen.

My 'Dating Tile' is an instance of my social tile class and I am tryin to enter Navigation as an Argument. I only seem to be able to return Null as per my printing feature.

I feel like the problem is with the constructor but I can't work it out.

I mean the problem could be I barley know what I'm doing but hey that's learning for you.

See below for the code to my problem.

This is the instance I'm trying to call it in.

```dart
class SocialTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const SocialTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
                end: Alignment.topLeft,
                stops: [0.25, 1],
                colors: [Color(0xff1A83E8), Color(0xffA111FF)]),
          ),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      socialTile(
                          tileTitle: 'messenger',
                          inputIcon: Icon(
                          )),
                      socialTile(
                          tileTitle: 'Dating',
                          inputIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.heart_broken_rounded,
                            size: 140,
                          ),
                          navigationToRoute: (context) => DatingPage(),),
                    ]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Class itself.

```dart
class socialTile extends GeneralUITile {
  const socialTile({
    Key? key,
    this.tileTitle = '',
    this.inputIcon,
    Widget Function(BuildContext)? navigationToRoute,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String tileTitle;
  final Icon? inputIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print(' $navigationToRoute Tap registered');
          if (navigationToRoute != null) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: navigationToRoute!),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 175,
          width: 175,
          color: Colors.purpleAccent,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              if (inputIcon != null) ...[inputIcon!],
              Text(
                '$tileTitle',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help, I'm ready to curl up in a ball and just start using Bard AI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to pass a route for every social tile you have, you can pass the widget for the next route, like:

```
socialTile(
   tileTitle: 'Dating',
   inputIcon: Icon(
       Icons.heart_broken_rounded,
       size: 140,
   ),
   navigationToWidget: DatingPage(),),
```

In your social tile file,

```
onTap: () {
       print(' $navigationToRoute Tap registered');
         if (navigationToRoute != null) {
           Navigator.push(
            context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=> navigationToWidget!),
        );
      }
 },
```

Your constructor should look like:

```
const socialTile({
    Key? key,
    this.tileTitle = '',
    this.inputIcon,
    this.navigationToWidget,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String tileTitle;
  final Icon? inputIcon;
  final Widget? navigationToWidget;
```